# Getting ORA-02391: SESSIONS_PER_USER limit

Tags: database, oracle

Is there a query which I can use to grab the amount of sessions I can use concurrently? I am threading some database connections and getting the error:

> ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit

How can I get the value for this limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the PROFILE for that user

```
select profile from dba_users where username = :who;
```

Then get the resource limit for that profile

```
SELECT P1.LIMIT AS "Concurrent Sessions (Per User)"
FROM   DBA_PROFILES P1
WHERE  P1.PROFILE       = :PROFILE
   AND P1.RESOURCE_NAME = 'SESSIONS_PER_USER';
```

Or

In SQL Developer, open the DBA panel and browse the users & profiles under 'security'

[image: browsing users and profiles in SQL Developer]

Answer (score 10):

start with this query to find out how many sessions you are using

```
select count(*) from v$session where username='YourUser';
```

then find out how many you are allowed in the profile for your user

```
select profile from dba_users where username ='YourUser';
```

finally

```
select PROFILE, LIMIT
from dba_profiles
WHERE RESOURCE_NAME = 'SESSIONS_PER_USER'
AND PROFILE = 'YourUserProfile';
```

and the fix

```
Alter profile YourUserProfile  limit SESSIONS_PER_USER 100;
```

Limits are in place for a reason as each session consumes resources. If you increase the limit some careful planning is in order for production systems so you don't run out of memory.

Comment: The count(*) from v$session is not perfectly exact because it doesn't include recursive DML sessions but in general usable.

Comment: when attempting to run select SESSIONS_PER_USER from dba_profiles where profile='YourUserProfile'; . I get a invalid identifier error for SESSIONS_PER_USER.

Answer (score 4):

It's profile setting

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_PROFILES WHERE RESOURCE_NAME = 'SESSIONS_PER_USER';
```

You can change it using

```
ALTER PROFILE <profile name> LIMIT SESSIONS_PER_USER <number>;
```

or

```
ALTER PROFILE <profile name> LIMIT SESSIONS_PER_USER UNLIMITED;
```

Comment: that would increase the limit for EVERY user assigned that PROFILE. you might want to create a new profile and adjust as necessary...

Answer (score 0):

While the other solutions provide statements on altering the user session limit, the diagnostic queries did not work for me, although I am a complete beginner and maybe performed it incorrectly. The following queries [from Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-fix-ora-02391-exceeded-simultaneous-sessions_per_user-limit-errors-in-jira-800867831.html) helped me.

For checking number of sessions per user, so you can see which users are nearing their limit:

```
SELECT count(*) as connections, 
       username 
FROM   v$session 
GROUP  BY username 
ORDER  BY username;
```

and to check what that limit is set to be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT username, 
                profile, 
                resource_name, 
                limit
FROM   dba_profiles 
       NATURAL JOIN dba_users 
WHERE  resource_name = 'SESSIONS_PER_USER';
```

From there, the rest of the linked site or other solutions here can presumably help with altering the limit to your needs.