# session per user limit exceeded

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

while execute some part of code of dao class i'm getting database ping failed as soon as i execute the output is getting displayed in the console but not in the browser.while execute some part of code of dao class i'm getting database ping failed as soon as i execute the output is getting displayed in the console but not in the browser

if i remove the getTransaction.commit() it'll show the output but update will not work. it fetches the count of upvote and downvotee and displays it but is i click on it again then again it shows ping failed

**here is the error**

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit


at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1018)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:501)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:437)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:954)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:639)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)

at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.oracle.JDBCOracleConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCOracleConnectionFactory.java:27)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)

at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

**and my dao class is**

```
public class TagDAOImpl implements TagDAO {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Map<Integer, String> viewQuestion(String question) throws Exception {
    Map<Integer, String> quesString = null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Session session = null;
    List<QuestionEntity> custList = new ArrayList<QuestionEntity>();
    try {
        quesString = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        QuestionEntity tag = new QuestionEntity();
        // Question q=new Question();
        // q.setTagId(question);
        // ques.setQuestionString(question.getQuestionString());
        System.out.println("dao" + question);

        // session.persist(ques);

        // session.getTransaction().begin();

        Query query = session
                .createQuery("from QuestionEntity where tagId=?");
        query.setString(0, question);
        custList = query.list();
        System.out.println(custList.size());
        // List list = query.list();
        for (QuestionEntity tagEntity : custList) {
            System.out
                    .println("Question ID=>" + tagEntity.getQuestionId()
                            + "\nQuestion String=>"
                            + tagEntity.getQuestionString());
            // List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
            Question q = new Question();
            q.setQuestionId(tagEntity.getQuestionId());
            q.setQuestionString(tagEntity.getQuestionString());
            // newList.addAll(getTag(tagEntity.getQuestionId()));
            // String a=String.valueOf(tagEntity.getQuestionId());
            quesString.put(q.getQuestionId(), q.getQuestionString());

            // quesString.add(a);
            // quesString.addAll(newList);

        }
        // session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (HibernateException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw new Exception("DAO.TECHNICAL_ERROR");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw exception;
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen() || session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return quesString;
}

// quesString.add();

// quesString.add("\n");

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
public Map<Integer, String> getAnswer(Integer question) throws Exception {
    Map<Integer, String> quesString = null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Session session = null;
    List<AnswerEntity> custList1 = new ArrayList<AnswerEntity>();
    try {
        quesString = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        AnswerEntity tag = new AnswerEntity();
        // Question q=new Question();
        // q.setTagId(question);
        // ques.setQuestionString(question.getQuestionString());
        System.out.println("dao" + question);

        // session.persist(ques);

        // session.getTransaction().begin();
        System.out.println("before query exec");
        Query query = session
                .createQuery("from AnswerEntity where questionId=?");
        query.setInteger(0, question);
        System.out.println(query);
        System.out.println("after query exec");
        custList1 = query.list();
        System.out.println(custList1.size());
        // List list = query.list();
        for (AnswerEntity tagEntity : custList1) {
            // System.out.println("Question ID=>"+tagEntity.getQuestionId()+"\nQuestion String=>"+tagEntity.getQuestionString());
            // List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
            Answer a = new Answer();
            a.setQuestionId(tagEntity.getQuestionId());
            a.setAnswerString(tagEntity.getAnswerString());
            // newList.addAll(getTag(tagEntity.getQuestionId()));
            // String a=String.valueOf(tagEntity.getQuestionId());
            quesString.put(a.getQuestionId(), a.getAnswerString());

            // quesString.add(a);
            // quesString.addAll(newList);

        }
        // session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (HibernateException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw new Exception("DAO.TECHNICAL_ERROR");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw exception;
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen() || session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return quesString;
}

public Map<Integer, String> getAllQuestions() throws Exception {
    Map<Integer, String> quesString = null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Session session = null;
    List<QuestionEntity> custList = new ArrayList<QuestionEntity>();
    try {
        quesString = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        QuestionEntity tag = new QuestionEntity();
        // Question q=new Question();
        // q.setTagId(question);
        // ques.setQuestionString(question.getQuestionString());
        // System.out.println("dao"+question);

        // session.persist(ques);

        // session.getTransaction().begin();

        Query query = session.createQuery("from QuestionEntity");
        // query.setString(0, question);
        custList = query.list();
        System.out.println(custList.size());
        // List list = query.list();
        for (QuestionEntity tagEntity : custList) {
            System.out
                    .println("Question ID=>" + tagEntity.getQuestionId()
                            + "\nQuestion String=>"
                            + tagEntity.getQuestionString());
            // List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
            Question q = new Question();
            q.setQuestionId(tagEntity.getQuestionId());
            q.setQuestionString(tagEntity.getQuestionString());
            // newList.addAll(getTag(tagEntity.getQuestionId()));
            // String a=String.valueOf(tagEntity.getQuestionId());
            quesString.put(q.getQuestionId(), q.getQuestionString());

            // quesString.add(a);
            // quesString.addAll(newList);

        }
        // session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (HibernateException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw new Exception("DAO.TECHNICAL_ERROR");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw exception;
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen() || session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return quesString;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Map<Integer, String> count(String tagged) throws Exception {
    Map<Integer, String> quesString = null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Session session = null;
    List<QuestionEntity> custList = new ArrayList<QuestionEntity>();
    try {
        quesString = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        QuestionEntity tag = new QuestionEntity();
        // Question q=new Question();
        // q.setTagId(question);
        // ques.setQuestionString(question.getQuestionString());
        // System.out.println("dao"+question);

        // session.persist(ques);

        // session.getTransaction().begin();

        Query query = session
                .createQuery("from QuestionEntity where tagId=?");
        query.setString(0, tagged);
        custList = query.list();
        System.out.println(custList.size());
        quesString.put(custList.size(), tagged);

        // session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (HibernateException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw new Exception("DAO.TECHNICAL_ERROR");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw exception;
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen() || session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return quesString;
}

public List<String> getTag(Integer question) throws Exception {
    List<String> quesString = null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Session session = null;

    try {
        quesString = new ArrayList<String>();
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        QuestionEntity tag = new QuestionEntity();
        // Question q=new Question();
        // q.setTagId(question);
        // ques.setQuestionString(question.getQuestionString());
        System.out.println("dao" + question);

        // session.persist(ques);

        // session.getTransaction().begin();

        Query query2 = session
                .createQuery("from QuestionEntity where questionId=?");
        query2.setInteger(0, question);
        List<QuestionEntity> tagList = query2.list();
        for (QuestionEntity tagEntity : tagList)
            System.out.println("custlist " + tagEntity.getTagId());

        // List list = query2.list();
        for (QuestionEntity tagEntity : tagList) {
            System.out.println("Question ID=>" + tagEntity.getQuestionId()
                    + "\nQuestion String=>" + tagEntity.getQuestionString()
                    + "\ntagId=>" + tagEntity.getTagId());
            quesString.add(tagEntity.getTagId());
            System.out.println(tagEntity.getTagId());

        }
        // session.getTransaction().commit();

        // quesString.add();

        // quesString.add("\n");

    } catch (HibernateException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw new Exception("DAO.TECHNICAL_ERROR");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw exception;
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen() || session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return quesString;
}

@Override
public Integer upvote(Integer questionId) throws Exception {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Session session = null;
    Integer updatedUpvote = null;
    try {
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println("key in like dao" + questionId);
        QuestionEntity qe = (QuestionEntity) session.get(
                QuestionEntity.class, questionId);
        if (qe != null) {
            // session.getTransaction().begin();
            updatedUpvote = qe.getUpvotes() + 1;
            System.out.println(updatedUpvote);
            qe.setUpvotes(updatedUpvote);
            System.out.println(qe.getUpvotes() + "entity");
            session.update(qe);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        }
    } catch (HibernateException exception) {
        throw new Exception("DAO.TECHNICAL_ERROR");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        throw exception;
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen() || session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return updatedUpvote;
}

@Override
public Integer downvote(Integer questionId) throws Exception {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Session session = null;
    Integer updatedDownvote = null;
    try {
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println("key in like dao" + questionId);
        QuestionEntity qe = (QuestionEntity) session.get(
                QuestionEntity.class, questionId);
        if (qe != null) {
            // session.getTransaction().begin();
            updatedDownvote = qe.getDownvotes() + 1;
            System.out.println(updatedDownvote);
            qe.setUpvotes(updatedDownvote);
            session.saveOrUpdate(qe);

        }
    } catch (HibernateException exception) {
        throw new Exception("DAO.TECHNICAL_ERROR");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        throw exception;
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen() || session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return updatedDownvote;
}

public String user(Integer question) throws Exception {
    // List<String> quesString =null;
    // String us="";
    String userFound = null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Session session = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("dao tag k try me");
        // quesString=new ArrayList<String>();
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        QuestionEntity tag = new QuestionEntity();

        System.out.println("dao" + question);

        // session.persist(ques);

        // session.getTransaction().begin();

        // Query query2 =
        // session.createQuery("select qe.userId from QuestionEntity qe where questionId=?");
        // query2.setString(0, question);
        QuestionEntity qe = (QuestionEntity) session.get(
                QuestionEntity.class, question);
        userFound = qe.getUserId();
        System.out.println(userFound);
        /*
         * for(QuestionEntity tagEntity:tagList){
         * System.out.println("UserID=>"+tagEntity.getUserId());
         * us=tagEntity.getUserId();
         * 
         * }
         */

    } catch (HibernateException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw new Exception("DAO.TECHNICAL_ERROR");
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("src/com/infy/resources/log4j.xml");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw exception;
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen() || session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return userFound;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is your Oracle DB is configured to support "x" number of concurrent sessions per user.
And hence you are tripping up on the issue.
You need to work with the person managing the DB to get your concurrent sessions per use increased.

See: [Getting ORA-02391: SESSIONS_PER_USER limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525642/getting-ora-02391-sessions-per-user-limit?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)